# How to fix pyDub Error "Decoding failed" while segmenting Audio

Tags: python, pydub, audiosegment

Initially the code below worked well. But once, during execution of the code i stopped the execution. Then, it constantly shows 'Decoding failed. ffmpeg returned error code:1'. My OS is linux mint.

What i've tried:

- Reinstalled pydub
- Tried solving the problem by creating new virtual environment
- Reinstalled ffmpeg

Code:

```
    for i in range(0,18,2):  
      t1 = i *1000  #in milisecond
      t2 = (i+2)*1000

      newAudio = AudioSegment.from_mp3("3b1b.mp3")
      newAudio = newAudio[t1:t2]

      newAudio.export("bike/"+str(count)+ '.mp3', format="wav")

      count +=1

      print(count)
```

Error looks like:

```
pydub.exceptions.CouldntDecodeError: Decoding failed. ffmpeg returned error code: 1

Output from ffmpeg/avlib:

b'ffmpeg version 3.4.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the 
FFmpeg developers\n  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)\n  
configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ub
```